# C# Working with objects (properly a byRef Byval problem)

Tags: c#

I have my Compressors class:

```
public class Compressors
{

    public Refrigerant Output { get; set; }
    public Refrigerant Input { get; set; }


// Constructor
    public Compressors(Refrigerant input)
    {
        Input = input; 
    }

}
```

In my main code I have:

```
var Compressor1 = new Compressors(BeforeComp);
var Compressor2 = new Compressors(Compressor1.Output);
```

Looking at is fine

```
Compressor1.Input
Compressor1.Output
```

But looking at

```
Compressor2.Input //Should be the same as Compressor1.Output!
```

returns a Null error

Summing up, I want Compressor1.Output and Compressor2.Input to refer to the same object.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should also initialize your `Output` property in your `Compressors` class!

Comment: public Compressors(Refrigerant input)
    {
        Input = input; Output = input;
    }

Comment: I think the title does not reflect the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working as expected.
You never initialize `Compressor1.Output`. It therefore is `null`. You use this value as the input for the constructor of `Compressor2`, which is the value that you will then see in `Compressor2.Input`.

In other words:

```
Assert.Equal(Compressor1.Output, Compressor2.Input);
Assert.Null(Compressor1.Output);
Assert.Null(Compressor2.Input);
```

Comment: I didn't vote on your answer, but you only explain why it doesn't work, not how to make it work.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I know, and I can't, because I don't know the logic behind these classes. Also initializing the Output with the input as others suggest seems not correct to me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback! It made me look elsewhere

I used this:

```
public Refrigerant ShallowCopy()
{
return (Refrigerant)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

to copy the values stored inside my Refrigerant-class.
I thought this would just copy values so I didn't have to

```
Output.x = Input.x
Output.y = Input.y
Output.z = Input.z
```

But it didn't work as intended